# На сервере не работает $_POST

Tags: php, post, rest, openserver, postman

Работаю с Retrofit2, Volley даже уже Postman тестил. Не работает $_POST на сервере. Он приходит пустым, и я даже не предполагаю как решить эту проблему. У кого было подобное отпишите что делали. Использую OpenServer последней версии. Такая ошибка наблюдается только на локалке. На удаленном сервере такой ошибки замечено не было. Если пробую использовать форму, то $_POST работает как надо. Но если отправляю с внешнего ресурса, то не работает ничего.

Принимаю значение

```
echo $_POST['say]
```

Comment: https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3360, может эта статья поможет

Comment: @entithat Используя то, что было в статье сервер все равно не видит данные которые я отправил.

Comment: Значит либо что-то не так отправляете, либо код не так написан. Гадать можно долго.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если я использую способ $_GET, то все работает. Стоит в коде поменять метод на post, он не работает. Я думаю проблема таки не в коде.

Comment: Вы покажите пример что откуда и куда отправляете. А то мы как на кофейной гуже тут гадаем. По вашим словам "отправляю с внешнего ресурса" можно предположить что у вас стоит CSRF. А если читать выше не понятно, зачем вы с внешнего ресурса на локалку отправляете и т.д. Дайте побольше инфы.

Comment: @Manitikyl Я возможно неправильно выразился. Отправляю через Postman с параметром $_POST['say']='hey' . На [скриншоте](https://imgur.com/QhepnpE) видно. Причем проблема не в коде это точно, так как когда я использовал библиотеку Volley на удаленном сервере(hostinger), $_POST работал так как надо. Сейчас же он работает только с формой. Под внешним ресурсом я имел в виду свою программу, неправильно выразился.

Comment: @Дмитрий так вы выберете `form-data` и должно работать :)

Comment: @Manitikyl К сожалению не работает :(

Comment: Как это не работает? Создайте на локалке скрипт: `<?php if (isset($_POST['test'])) {echo $_POST['test'];}else{echo '-';}` - и пошлите на него POST запрос с `form-data`, где `ключ`=`test` значение - любое. если увидите в ответе свое значение значит все работает

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то в `Postman` у вас вверху это как вкладки, Перейдите на вкладку `x-www-form-urlencoded` - удалите все что есть, и так везде. Потом перейдите на `form-data` - и создайте новую переменную, которая вам нужна.

Comment: @Manitikyl Все сделал, ответ пришел в виде значение else. https://imgur.com/qlKuBNi. 

<?php
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {echo $_POST['test'];}else{echo '-';}
?> - код скрипта

Comment: А что за путь такой? Вы используете фреймворк? Создайте прям конкретно отдельный файл `test.php` и к нему обращение

Comment: @Manitikyl Там есть перенаправление, если после папки ничего не написано, оно index.php добавляет. Если бы путь был нерабочий он не вывел ничего бы

Comment: @Дмитрий перенаправление может терять данные формы, уберите его

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо